# Incomprehensible runtime error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, bulletphysics

I just upgraded to use IntelliJ instead of eclipse with maven and jme3 0.1 beta. Now I get an incomprehesible error msg:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7532 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/dac/Downloads/idea-IU-145.972.3/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/dac/proj/spaceworld/target/classes:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/core.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/xpp3.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/lwjgl.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/nifty.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jinput.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jsr305.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jutils.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/simple.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/dense64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/vecmath.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/denseC64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/eventbus.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/j-ogg-all.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-core.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-jogg.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-jogl.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-main.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-lwjgl.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jglfont-core.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-blender.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-desktop.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-effects.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-jbullet.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-plugins.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-terrain.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-niftygui.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-testdata.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-main.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/nifty-examples.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-main.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jme3-networking.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/nifty-style-black.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/nifty-default-controls.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-linux-armv6.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-solaris-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-android-armv6.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-solaris-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/lwjgl-platform-natives-osx.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jinput-platform-natives-osx.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-android-aarch64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-linux-armv6.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/lwjgl-platform-natives-linux.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jinput-platform-natives-linux.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/joal-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-solaris-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-armv6.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-android-armv6.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-solaris-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/lwjgl-platform-natives-windows.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-solaris-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jinput-platform-natives-windows.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-android-armv6.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-solaris-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-android-aarch64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-android-aarch64.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/cai-nmgen-0.2.0.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/cz/advel/jbullet/jbullet/20101010/jbullet-20101010.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/java3d/vecmath/1.3.1/vecmath-1.3.1.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/asm/asm-all/3.1/asm-all-3.1.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/cogchar/ext.bundle.opengl.nifty/1.0.9.1/ext.bundle.opengl.nifty-1.0.9.1.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/bushe/eventbus/1.3/eventbus-1.3.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.4c/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/jmonkeyengine/jme3-core/3.1.0-beta1/jme3-core-3.1.0-beta1.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/jmonkeyengine/jme3-desktop/3.1.0-beta1/jme3-desktop-3.1.0-beta1.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/jmonkeyengine/jme3-lwjgl/3.1.0-beta1/jme3-lwjgl-3.1.0-beta1.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.3/lwjgl-2.9.3.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.3/lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-windows.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.3/lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-linux.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.3/lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-osx.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/net/java/jinput/jinput/2.0.5/jinput-2.0.5.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/net/java/jutils/jutils/1.0.0/jutils-1.0.0.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar:/home/dac/.m2/repository/net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar:/home/dac/Downloads/idea-IU-145.972.3/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain spaceworld.UFOSpaceWorld
Jun 22, 2016 6:25:47 AM com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem initialize
INFO: Running on jMonkeyEngine 3.1-beta1
 * Branch: HEAD
 * Git Hash: 310f4db
 * Build Date: 2016-04-25
Jun 22, 2016 6:25:48 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: LWJGL 2.9.3 context running on thread jME3 Main
 * Graphics Adapter: null
 * Driver Version: null
 * Scaling Factor: 1
Jun 22, 2016 6:25:48 AM com.jme3.renderer.opengl.GLRenderer loadCapabilitiesCommon
INFO: OpenGL Renderer Information
 * Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
 * Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) 
 * OpenGL Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
 * GLSL Version: 1.30
 * Profile: Compatibility
Jun 22, 2016 6:25:48 AM com.jme3.audio.openal.ALAudioRenderer initOpenAL
INFO: Audio Renderer Information
 * Device: OpenAL Soft
 * Vendor: OpenAL Community
 * Renderer: OpenAL Soft
 * Version: 1.1 ALSOFT 1.15.1
 * Supported channels: 64
 * ALC extensions: ALC_ENUMERATE_ALL_EXT ALC_ENUMERATION_EXT ALC_EXT_CAPTURE ALC_EXT_DEDICATED ALC_EXT_disconnect ALC_EXT_EFX ALC_EXT_thread_local_context ALC_SOFT_loopback
 * AL extensions: AL_EXT_ALAW AL_EXT_DOUBLE AL_EXT_EXPONENT_DISTANCE AL_EXT_FLOAT32 AL_EXT_IMA4 AL_EXT_LINEAR_DISTANCE AL_EXT_MCFORMATS AL_EXT_MULAW AL_EXT_MULAW_MCFORMATS AL_EXT_OFFSET AL_EXT_source_distance_model AL_LOKI_quadriphonic AL_SOFT_buffer_samples AL_SOFT_buffer_sub_data AL_SOFTX_deferred_updates AL_SOFT_direct_channels AL_SOFT_loop_points AL_SOFT_source_latency
Jun 22, 2016 6:25:48 AM com.jme3.audio.openal.ALAudioRenderer initOpenAL
WARNING: Pausing audio device not supported.
Jun 22, 2016 6:25:48 AM com.jme3.audio.openal.ALAudioRenderer initOpenAL
INFO: Audio effect extension version: 1.0
Jun 22, 2016 6:25:48 AM com.jme3.audio.openal.ALAudioRenderer initOpenAL
INFO: Audio max auxiliary sends: 4
Jun 22, 2016 6:25:49 AM com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState startPhysicsOnExecutor
SEVERE: null
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.bulletphysics.dynamics.DiscreteDynamicsWorld.setPreTickCallback(Lcom/bulletphysics/dynamics/InternalTickCallback;)V
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState.startPhysicsOnExecutor(BulletAppState.java:121)
    at com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState.startPhysics(BulletAppState.java:162)
    at com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState.stateAttached(BulletAppState.java:211)
    at com.jme3.app.state.AppStateManager.attach(AppStateManager.java:133)
    at spaceworld.UFOSpaceWorld.simpleInitApp(UFOSpaceWorld.java:156)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:220)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.bulletphysics.dynamics.DiscreteDynamicsWorld.setPreTickCallback(Lcom/bulletphysics/dynamics/InternalTickCallback;)V
    at com.jme3.bullet.PhysicsSpace.setTickCallback(PhysicsSpace.java:282)
    at com.jme3.bullet.PhysicsSpace.create(PhysicsSpace.java:215)
    at com.jme3.bullet.PhysicsSpace.<init>(PhysicsSpace.java:179)
    at com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState$1.call(BulletAppState.java:115)
    at com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState$1.call(BulletAppState.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

Jun 22, 2016 6:25:49 AM com.jme3.app.LegacyApplication handleError
SEVERE: Uncaught exception thrown in Thread[jME3 Main,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState.startPhysics(BulletAppState.java:166)
    at com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState.stateAttached(BulletAppState.java:211)
    at com.jme3.app.state.AppStateManager.attach(AppStateManager.java:133)
    at spaceworld.UFOSpaceWorld.simpleInitApp(UFOSpaceWorld.java:156)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:220)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What does it mean?

I removed all the external jars and used the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>jme3-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>JME3 maven project</name>

    <properties>
        <jme3.version>3.1.0-beta1</jme3.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cz.advel.jbullet/jbullet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.advel.jbullet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbullet</artifactId>
            <version>20101010</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cogchar/ext.bundle.opengl.nifty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cogchar</groupId>
            <artifactId>ext.bundle.opengl.nifty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-desktop</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-networking</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-jbullet</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-plugins</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-bullet</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-effects</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-blender</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmonkeyengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>jme3-bullet-native</artifactId>
            <version>${jme3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bintray-jmonkeyengine-org.jmonkeyengine</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/jmonkeyengine/org.jmonkeyengine</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: This looks like it might be caused by a missing depedency/dependency problem.  Have you configured your dependencies yet from IntelliJ?

Comment: Probably more a wrong version rather than a missing dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace it seems you have classpath conflicts.

Some of your dependency libraries are in classpath under `/home/dac/Downloads/lib/*` and some get pulled in through maven under `/home/dac/.m2/*`

Likely you previously configured your local classpath manually either through environment variable or through the IDE but later in use maven which might get newer version of the library but your manually downloaded library still old version missing some methods.

Check your environment variable or IDE configuration to remove the manually downloaded libraries from your classpath.